# i am working on moveit using ubuntu 20.04. i found this error when i make catkin_make. can someone help me please

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"robot_state_controller" with any of the following names:

```
robot_state_controllerConfig.cmake
robot_state_controller-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "robot_state_controller" to
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "robot_state_controller_DIR" to a directory
containing one of the above files.  If "robot_state_controller" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
for_moveit/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/betty/ws_moveit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/betty/ws_moveit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:320: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379887/i-am-working-on-moveit-using-ubuntu-20.04.-i-found-this-error-when-i-make-catkin_make.-can-someone-help-me-please/) by [lehem_d](https://answers.ros.org/users/75717/lehem_d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Just try to install this package and check everything is working or not.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-robot-state-publisher
```

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lehem_d](https://answers.ros.org/users/75717/lehem_d/) on 2021-06-09**:
i do that still it didn't work

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-06-09**:
Try to build from source: https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher

**Comment by [lehem_d](https://answers.ros.org/users/75717/lehem_d/) on 2021-06-09**:
how do i bulid that

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-06-09**:
by going into your workspace src folder and clone from https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher this link. then build the workspace directory.

**Comment by [lehem_d](https://answers.ros.org/users/75717/lehem_d/) on 2021-06-09**:
i already do that still not working.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-06-09**:
You are getting the same error or different?

**Comment by [lehem_d](https://answers.ros.org/users/75717/lehem_d/) on 2021-06-09**:
same error

**Comment by [lehem_d](https://answers.ros.org/users/75717/lehem_d/) on 2021-06-09**:
now it work thanks a lot for your help